# Resolve into four factors: $\dfrac{xy^3}{72}-\dfrac{x^3y^5}{32}-\dfrac{1}{9x^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Resolve into four factors: $\dfrac{xy^3}{72}-\dfrac{x^3y^5}{32}-\dfrac{1}{9x^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{4}$

$\Rightarrow xy^3(\dfrac{1}{72}-\dfrac{x^2y^2}{32})+[(\dfrac{y}{2})^2-(\dfrac{1}{3x})^2]$

$\Rightarrow xy^3(\dfrac{4}{288}-\dfrac{9x^2y^2}{288})+(\dfrac{y}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3x})(\dfrac{y}{2}-\dfrac{1}{3x})$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{xy^3}{288}[(2)^2-(3xy)^2]+(\dfrac{3xy+2}{6x})(\dfrac{3xy-2}{6x})$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{xy^3}{288}(2+3xy)(2-3xy)+\dfrac{1}{36x^2}(3xy+2)(3xy-2)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{xy^3}{288}(2+3xy)(2-3xy)-\dfrac{1}{36x^2}(2+3xy)(2-3xy)$

$\Rightarrow (\dfrac{xy^3}{288}-\dfrac{1}{36x^2})(2+3xy)(2-3xy)$

$\Rightarrow (\dfrac{x^3y^3-8}{288x^2})(2+3xy)(2-3xy)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{288x^2}(xy-2)(x^2y^2+2xy+4)(2+3xy)(2-3xy)$

So this answer is correct. However, it is five factors, not four. The book gives the correct answer with four factors:

$(\dfrac{1}{3x}+\dfrac{y}{2})(\dfrac{1}{3x}-\dfrac{y}{2})(\dfrac{xy}{2}-1)(\dfrac{x^2y^2}{4}+\dfrac{xy}{2}+1)$

My question is I'm not sure how to get to four factors, since in the very first step of the calculation I took out $\dfrac{1}{288}$ from the first parenthesis. Not taking out $\dfrac{1}{288}$ would make the calculations needlessly difficult. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You can move the $\frac 1{x^2}$ out front into two of your factors to make the $x$'s and $y$'s match up with the book answer.  I don't think they count a numeric prefactor, so that gets you to $4$ factors.  However the numerics inside the factors do not seem to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
 \dfrac{1}{288x^2}(xy-2)(x^2y^2+2xy+4)(2+3xy)(2-3xy)
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{288x^2} \cdot 2\cdot (\frac{xy}{2}-1)(x^2y^2+xy+4)(2+3xy)(2-3xy) \\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{288x^2} \cdot 2\cdot 4 \cdot (\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(2+3xy)(2-3xy)\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{288x^2} \cdot 2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot(\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{xy}{2})(2-3xy) \\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{288x^2} \cdot 2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot(\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{xy}{2})(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{xy}{2})
$$
This gives
$$
\dfrac{1}{x^2} (\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{xy}{2})(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{xy}{2})
$$
we can now do the $x$
$$
\dfrac{1}{x^2} \cdot x \cdot x \cdot(\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{y}{2})(\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{y}{2})
$$
and you reach your $4$ factors
$$
(\frac{xy}{2}-1)(\frac{x^2y^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{y}{2})(\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{y}{2})
$$
that being said, this was because I am mapping to your `textbook answer` as opposed to any real insight.